# ArcGIS (ArcObjects) Windows 7 - 64 bit -support

Tags: arcobjects, arcgis-9.3, c++, windows-7, qt

I have been developing with ArcGIS Cross Platform C++ SDK (with Qt 4.8.2) on 32 bit Windows XP SP3 (development machine). I used to use MapTool Control within ArcObjects on the development machine. Moreover I compile my application with Visual Studio 2010 in both release and debug mode. I installed Engine Runtime on Windows 7 (both 32 bit and 64 bit) on the test machines, however my application simply crashes on both machines whenever 

`new QAxCtl(AoPROGID_MapControl, &mapctl, Map Control");`

is called in my application. However, my application works on another machine running Windows XP SP3 which makes me believe that the cause of the problem is Windows 7 (or something I forgot about Windows 7). I am not familiar with ArcGIS and even I am not sure if I installed everything necessary for the test machines (I just installed just engine runtime and use a valid license). I wonder if using QAxCtl for controls is possible on Windows 7?

Comment: Are you 100% that that is a 32 bit application? That doesn't explain the win7 32 though.. if you've compiled for 'any cpu' it won't be able to talk to ArcGIS.

Comment: Any CPU? Is it C# (.NET) or C++ (native)?